# Apache camel maven project addRouteBuilder not found

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I have created a new project with maven archetype apache-camel but after building project I am getting an error when adding a route builder. Hereby you can find the code:

```
import org.apache.camel.main.Main; 

Main main = new Main(); 
main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
main.run(args);
```

and below the error I get:

> Error: java: cannot find symbol symbol: method addRouteBuilder

I am completely new and after trying for hours couldn't figure out what is wrong. Kindly guide me

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide more context. For example: what is the object `main`? Does the defining class define a method called `addRouteBuilder`?

Comment: Thankyou. Below is import of main and initialization

import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

 Main main = new Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
        main.run(args);

Comment: I integrated your comment into the original question. 
I do not know how Apache Camel works, but, generally, if you manage to build, but not to run, the you usually are not exporting some dependency that is available at compile-time (thus not giving you errors when you build, but only when you run). Are you using a build automation tool, such as Maven or Gradle? In this case, you might want to edit the question adding the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue today.  The IntelliJ code generator is wrong.

Change the code as below

from

> main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

To

> main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

NOTE: its addRoute"s"Builder not addRouteBuilder

Comment: That's great.  Please update the response to Answered